# Drupal 7 Progress bar for Webform file uploads empty iframe

Tags: php, iframe, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I'm trying to use this Drupal 7 module and it's installed correctly, but when I go to my webform select a file and press upload it doesn't show a progress bar for how long the upload takes. The module prints an iframe in the div, but the body tag in this iframe is empty.

The console doesnt return any errors.

Here is an example from what happens:

[image: Example from what happens]

The body tag is there but it is just empty.

On the https://www.drupal.org/node/1162654 where you can download the module people said adding PECL uploadprogress to your php extensions would fix the problem, but that didn't work for me. Does anyone know whats going on here what did i do wrong?

XAMPP doesn't return any errors when I start it up i'm using PHP 5.6 and the right PECL uploadprogress PHP 5.6 version.

If you need more information just post it in the comments.

Thanks for reading/helping.

Comment: What OS are you running on & what does the Drupal status report say under Upload progress?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2247421 -> try out the first comment, maybe you'll be lucky

Comment: In the Webform File component you've also set the Progress indicator to "Bar with progress meter"? FYI: The Drupal built-in uses a different element (not that body tag) shown through Ajax after hitting the upload button. Does it need to be with that module or would Drupal's built-in functionality also do?